# Fujitsu RX100 S6 hot swap without bios option in Debian 11

Tags: hotswap

I have old Fujitsu RX100 S6 with Debian 11 on it. How to change Debian settings so he will recognize hotswap bays. There is no "hot swap" option in bios.

Comment: if a device is mounted it is active and if not it can be plugged and removed as usual

Comment: you have to manually add it with root credentials